# convert string response to array of json objects

Tags: python, json

I am receiving a response that I need to save as CSV file. So I would like to convert the response string as an array of json objects then access all the objects and convert each to json and push to another array to write to a csv with `csv.writerow()`. Probably this is too much steps and can be reduced. But I am currently searching for a way to convert the response to an array. Here is the response sample along with code of trial:

```
import json

null = -1

response_object = """[{
"a" : "1",
"b" : "2",
"c" : "null"
}, {
"d" : "3",
"e" : "4",
"f" : "null"
}] 
"""

jess_dict = json.dumps(response_object)

jeson_converted = json.loads(jess_dict)

print(jeson_converted)
```

since the response object is not a valid json, I am not sure what I should do to convert it. Please suggest.

Comment: *”since the response object is not a valid json”* — What? Why?

Comment: @deceze As I said I need to save it to a csv file. I have no control over the response structure.

Comment: You didn’t explain why that JSON is supposedly not valid.

Comment: this json is valid, you can test with a JSON Online Validator

Comment: @Fred Thanks. I noticed it is running well now.

Answer (score 2):

`json.dumps` is for getting string dump from a json. Here You have a string already, so you don't need to dump it.

If You just use `loads`, It will give You a list of dicts:

```py
...
jeson_converted = json.loads(response_object)
print(jeson_converted)
```

Output:

```py
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'null'}, {'d': '3', 'e': '4', 'f': 'null'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. While iterating, I am getting a key error with this code: `
for x in jeson_converted: 
    print(x["a"])`

Comment: @Rifat Well, the second dict in the list doesn't have a key `a`.

Comment: @deceze can I get a way to convert the second dict as a list to iterate those values as well? I tried to convert x to a json.

Comment: @Rifat This makes no sense. What exactly do you think you need to do with this?

Comment: @deceze I would like to print each `a` if any or any element from all the json objects in the array.

Comment: @Rifat "Each `a` _or_ any element"? Well, which is it?

Comment: any or all elements.

Comment: @Rifat `for x in jeson_converted: for k, v in x.items(): print(k, v)`…?!

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me using `literal_eval` method from `ast` package to parse string representation of list, check if it's useful in your case:

```
import ast
parsed_response_object = ast.literal_eval(response_object)
for json_obj in parsed_response_object:
    print(json_obj)
```

Output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'null'}
{'d': '3', 'e': '4', 'f': 'null'}
```